# Does ServiceStack now support Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client?

Tags: odp.net, ormlite-servicestack

ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs class uses `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle/OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs). But the Oracle Provider Notes still tells that the Oracle provider requires an installation of Oracle's unmanaged ODP.NET [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#oracle-provider-notes).

If the ServiceStack Oracle Provider Notes are still valid, why does *ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle* use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` and not the unmanaged `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`?

Comment: Currently the switch to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is not complete. Follow ServiceStack Forum here: https://forums.servicestack.net/t/is-the-managed-oracle-data-provider-for-net-now-supported/7188 and here https://forums.servicestack.net/t/oracle-and-netcore/6781/7